# Install4j SQL script statement delimiter

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to use the SQL script action.  My statements are separated by ; and a new line.  Simply using ; as the statement delimiter is the best luck I've had, but unfortunately some of my statements have ; in the values and it breaks on those.  I've tried using

```
;$
;\n
\);
```

but it keeps trying to execute the whole script as a single statement.   I can't figure out where i'm going wrong here.

I'm using version 8.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug that will be fixed in 8.0.5. Both `;$` and `;\n` will work in 8.0.5. To get a build where this is already fixed, please contact support@ej-technologies.com.